# in Android Which View to use and how to display n values per page

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

This is for example as I haven't coded it yet, since I don't know how to start.

Let's say in Android I have String array with 100 values:

```
String[] myString = new String[100];
for (int number = 0; number < 100; number++) {
    myString[number] = "image " + number;
}
```

Which way should I display for example 5 values per page (which view to use (table, grid) and should I use Fragment replace for each page).

I would like to achieve something [like this](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html), but in Android. I just need some guidelines to start.

Comment: It's called a `ListView`. It needs an `adapter` to be filled from a `cursor` and to be the source for the custom row item Views (TextViews, in this case).

Comment: Your for loop loops 101 times, while the array is of size 100.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein So you are saying I need an adapter to display 5 items in ListView per Fragment while under fragment is his number so user can click on which page to go?

Comment: @user3249477 my bad ... for loop is just for example at the moment.

Comment: No... for only 5 items an ArrayAdapter will be enough. But you don't even need pagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if you have noticed, explicit pagination is not so often done in android, instead, infinite scrolling is used, for example your news feed in Facebook is a list, when you reach the bottom, it loads more and you can scroll more, at the bottom of that it loads again.

To implement this, it is quite easy, just set an `onScrollListener` and override `onScrollStateChanged()` method.

Set onScrollListener after initializing your ListView:

```
//In onCreate()

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setOnScrollListener(new ListScrollListener());
```

Make your listener class:

```
private class ListScrollListener implements OnScrollListener{

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listView.getCount()-1) {
                    page_num++;
                    //TODO Load more list items.
                    //notify the adapter of the listview that data has changed
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            //This can be left blank
        }

    }
```

If you want you can add a footer with a `ProgressBar` to your `ListView` to display when  you are loading more items with `listView.addFooterView(View v);`

You can find a nice tutorial about a custom ListView [at Vogella tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: @MePo Make sure that if your load more elements operation can take time( retrieving from server or file reading oepration etc...) then execute a new `AsyncTask` thread there, and move `notifyDataSetChanged()` to `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask`

Comment: I am retrieving from Database and the problem was I had too many values(using table with ScrollView at the moment) and it took some time to load. But this will give me the speed that I needed.